# Java Array List run time error source not found

Tags: java, arraylist

I am using `ArrayList` of type `Chromosome`(My own class). I have added elements from Arrays of type Chromosome to `ArrayList`. Now I want to access the element from `ArrayList`. I am using `Arraylist.get(index).chromosomeMethod()`.

But I am not getting the output. There is a runtime error. Compiler is saying source not found.

---

```
 while( y<25)
 {
     if(y == 24)
     {
         ChromosomeClust1.add(bin1[randomSequence[bin1counter]]);
         bin1counter++;
         ChromosomeClust2.add(bin2[randomSequence1[bin2counter]]);
         bin2counter++;
         ChromosomeClust3.add(bin3[randomSequence2[bin3counter]]);
         bin3counter++;
         ChromosomeClust4.add(bin4[randomSequence3[bin4counter]]);
         bin4counter++;
         y++;
     }
     else
     {
         ChromosomeClust1.add(bin1[randomSequence[bin1counter]]);
         bin1counter++;
         ChromosomeClust1.add(bin2[randomSequence1[bin2counter]]);
         bin2counter++;
         ChromosomeClust1.add(bin3[randomSequence2[bin3counter]]);
         bin3counter++;
         ChromosomeClust1.add(bin4[randomSequence3[bin4counter]]);
         bin4counter++;
         y++;

         ChromosomeClust2.add(bin1[randomSequence[bin1counter]]);
         bin1counter++;
         ChromosomeClust2.add(bin2[randomSequence1[bin2counter]]);
         bin2counter++;
         ChromosomeClust2.add(bin3[randomSequence2[bin3counter]]);
         bin3counter++;
         ChromosomeClust2.add(bin4[randomSequence3[bin4counter]]);
         bin4counter++;
         y++;
         ChromosomeClust3.add(bin1[randomSequence[bin1counter]]);
         bin1counter++;
         ChromosomeClust3.add(bin2[randomSequence1[bin2counter]]);
         bin2counter++;
         ChromosomeClust3.add(bin3[randomSequence2[bin3counter]]);
         bin3counter++;
         ChromosomeClust3.add(bin4[randomSequence3[bin4counter]]);
         bin4counter++;
         y++;
         ChromosomeClust4.add(bin1[randomSequence[bin1counter]]);
         bin1counter++;
         ChromosomeClust4.add(bin2[randomSequence1[bin2counter]]);
         bin2counter++;
         ChromosomeClust4.add(bin3[randomSequence2[bin3counter]]);
         bin3counter++;
         ChromosomeClust4.add(bin4[randomSequence3[bin4counter]]);
         bin4counter++;
         y++;
     }

 }
```

---

```
    int q = ChromosomeClust1.size();

    boolean k = ChromosomeClust1.isEmpty();

    if(k==true)
    {
        System.out.print("List empty");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("Not Empty");
        System.out.println(ChromosomeClust1.get(2).getRows());
    }
```

Comment: It also says what source cannot be found. Please post the stack trace containing this information.

Comment: Provide us piece of code when you add sth to list and when you try to get it from list.

Comment: first show code and print error it is giving...

Comment: The above part of the code is from Main Class. Here i am just checking that weather elemnts are added in array list of not Error was Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException. The error came at this line:
System.out.println(ChromosomeClust1.get(2).getRows());

Comment: How are your arrays created and filled?

Comment: I am new to stack overflow. I pasted my code but moderator deleted it. I dont know why :(